# Changing Text color of selected item in RecyclerView OnClick

Tags: android-recyclerview, textview

I want to change the text color of the only selected view in my recycler view. The code below works by changing the background color but I also need to change the text color of the selected item.

The change of the text color of the selected must be inside the onClick and not inside onBindViewHolder.

The following is my code which works fine for the background color change.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    public interface ListItemClickListener{
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }
    private final ArrayList<String> groups;
    private final ListItemClickListener mOnClickListener;
    View prevElement = null;

    /**
     * Provide a reference to the type of views that you are using
     * (custom ViewHolder)
     */
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private final TextView textView;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View v) {
            super(v);
            textView = v.findViewById(R.id.group_view);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // The user may not set a click listener for list items, in which case our listener
            // will be null, so we need to check for this
            if (mOnClickListener != null) {
                mOnClickListener.onItemClick(v, getLayoutPosition());
            }
            if (prevElement != null) {
                prevElement.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            }
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
            prevElement = v;
        }
        public TextView getTextView() {
            return textView;
        }
    }
    /**
     * Initialize the dataset of the Adapter
     *
     * @param groups String[] containing the data to populate views to be used
     * by RecyclerView
    */
    public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<String> groups,ListItemClickListener mOnClickListener) {
        this.groups = groups;
        this.mOnClickListener = mOnClickListener;
    }


    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        // Create a new view, which defines the UI of the list item
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.group_layout, viewGroup, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        String txt = groups.get(position);
        viewHolder.getTextView().setText(txt);

    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return groups.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update your onClick method with below method then you'll get the same output as expected**

Kotlin:

```
override fun onClick(v: View) {
        // The user may not set a click listener for list items, in which case our listener
        // will be null, so we need to check for this
        mOnClickListener.onItemClick(v, layoutPosition)
        if (prevElement != null) {
            prevElement.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
            if(prevElement instanceof TextView)
                  (TextView)(prevElement).setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
        }
        textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN)
        textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
        prevElement = textView
    }
```

In Java:

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    mOnClickListener.onItemClick(v, getLayoutPosition());
    if (prevElement != null) {
        prevElement.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        if(prevElement instanceof TextView)
            ((TextView) prevElement).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
    textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
    textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    prevElement = textView;
}
```

Comment: I wanted Java code but will try to convert your suggested kotlin into java and see if it works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: See If you need  java code. Then I can share with you. Just let me know if you face any issue in conversion.

Comment: @jiija I have update my answer. Please check Java code in my post. Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to change the code as below and it's working as I expected. @Ritika, thanks for your help mate.

```
    private TextView prevTextView = null;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mOnClickListener != null) {
            mOnClickListener.onItemClick(v, getLayoutPosition());
        }
        if (prevTextView != null) {
            prevTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            prevTextView.setTextColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        }
        textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        prevTextView = textView;
    }
```

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdgCA.png)